# What is the most optimized way of storing/compressing a black and white PNG

Tags: compression, imagemagick, png

I have a 4mb *transparent* PNG that is overlaid on a white background. So maybe we can get rid of transparency and just make it white for the web, to optimize. But then the question is, what else can be done? Should it be converted into a JPG? Should the JPG be compressed in other ways?

Basically, what ImageMagick command should be run to optimally compress this black and white (2 tone) image for the web, without changing it's size or visible quality (too much, if possible).

My initial attempt was just this:

```
convert myimg.png myimg.jpg
```

But it went from 3.2mb to 9.6mb!

Even doing this it was 6.2mb:

```
convert myimg.png -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 85% -colorspace gray +dither -colors 2 -type bilevel myimg.jpg
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PNG Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062332/png-compression)

Comment: Perhaps you can post your myimg.png. Why would you do -gaussian blur. That will add more data by creating more colors. Then you convert to binary again? Why not just strip and convert to Group4 or RLE compressed TIFF? (Untested)

Comment: How big is the PNG in pixels? Uniform areas in PNG compress very well, much better than any decent-quality JPG. You could have some luck with the [WebP format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP).